# UIScrollView bounces half page when at its bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, bounce

I have a scrollview in my app. It works fine, but when it's at its edges (beginning and the last photo), it bounces... bad. If I try to scroll it bounces me back correctly, but if I do it stronger (faster) it bounces half to the previous photo.

It's easier to make you see what I mean, here's a video I took (sorry for the quality, it's taken with an iPad :D )

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wErAyetyBw

Comment: That looks perfectly fine and normal to me.

Comment: It's not normal, a scrollview with Paging NEVER stops between a page and another.

Comment: I can't get that to work. My scrollview swiped like yours to the right, never shows a part of the previous left item when bouncing back. In XIB in the attribute inspector - Scroll View, I have just 4 items selected: scrolling and paging enabled, bounces, bounces horizontally.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? If not, can you post the code you're using to switch pages in your UIScrollView ? I have some code that I use every time I have a scroll view, but it would be easier to correct yours.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Three20 for photo viewing with this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer).

Comment: Hi Tuyen, thank you but I spent hours to write this photo slider, and now it has this only little bug, so I'd like to solve it, instead of replacing the whole programming with a ready-to-use pack :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that this was because an incorrect count of the scroll view width. Thanks for all the comments and answers!